# Как не обновлять значение в массиве, когда обновляется переменная запушенная в него?

Tags: javascript, html

```
let check = {
    value:1
}

let checkmas = [];
    checkmas.push(check);
$('.checkbtn').click((e)=>{
    check.value++;

    });
//bebug
setInterval(()=>{
    console.log('checkmas');
    console.log(checkmas);
    console.log('check');
    console.log(check);
},8000)
//
```

Здесь после того как обновляется значение check.value почему то так же обновляется значение в массиве хотя я его не меняю( я хочу чтобы в массиве значение оставалось прежним = 1, но когда я дабавляю check.value++ оно так же дабавляется в массиве. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"почему то"? Потому что это один и тот же объект. Создавайте новый объект для добавления в массив.

```
let check = {
  value: 1
};

let checkmas = [];
checkmas.push({ value: check.value });
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @АбылайНемс Пожалуйста. Успехов.